# Forms Authentication with Active Directory and Domain Policies

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, forms-authentication

I have rather strange kind of requirement.I want to use forms authentication with Active Directory but I do not want to set the minimum password length and other policy related settings in my applications web.config file.
I want it to follow default domain account policies so that when the domain level policy is changed (say minimum password length is changed to 8),I do not need to change it in web.config.

Is it possible?Any help or references are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you store the users of the web application?

Comment: I don't see the problem. If you store them in the AD, then the AD itself will enforce its own password policy.

Comment: then can i assume that I do not need to enforce any password policy in my web.config and AD will take care and consequently changing the policy in AD will reflect in the application behaviour?

Comment: I believe if you make a policy in AD, then it will enforce it for all new passwords from that point in time. Noone can get around it, not even forms authentication. I don't see why there would be an exception. Maybe the error message will be different if different layers catch the policy violation.

Comment: fejesjoco is right.  You don't have to set a policy on the web side, it's enforced by AD.  You can use the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider to do the authentication and even password reset if you don't want to roll your own authentication provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following link.  The easiest way is to use the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider

```
  Http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650308.aspx
```

If this doesn't meet your needs you can always roll your own membership provider, but I have found this link adequate for most cases.

Comment: thanks but that doesn't help..I do not want to set any properties in my providers section..i want them to be read from domain account policies..